# Create C# method which do specific task when a programm is run with shortcut

Tags: c#, click, task, shortcut

I have a programm written on c# in Visual Studio by another programmer and I want it to do specific task when I run it with shortcut.
Now the mechanism is working, when the application is re-launched, the new application tries to find the one already running (collapsed into the tray) and activate it, and close itself.
It needs to be finalized so that in this case the task list is also updated - as if the user clicked on the "Update" button.

[image: image here]

The programm has this button for refresh tasks. When I click on shortcut the programm must do: 
`barButtonItem_Refresh.PerformClick();`

I think I need to create a method where I will write this code.
I don’t know how to create this method or I do not know how this event is called, please tell me if you used it and write how to create this method.

Comment: `I think I need to create a method where I will write this code. I don’t know how to create this method or I do not know how this event is called, please tell me if you used it and write how to create this method.` << I am not sure how can I help you with this. Have you checked the code behind and fully understand the solution/project?

Comment: So, you need your second process to send a message to the first that it should do the refresh. For this you need some form of IPC, a shared WaitEventHandle might be sufficient, but there are named pipes and many other methods.